# Why is SpaCy matcher not matching case-insensitive words in a document?

Tags: spacy, case-insensitive, matcher

I want SpaCy matcher to match keywords (multi-word entities) in a document irrespective of their case.

Token.lemma is case sensitive... So, with this code, I can only find "product preferences" rather than "PRODUCT PREFERENCES" or "Product Preferences" in my document.

```
    pat_piece = ({"LEMMA": token.lemma_.lower()} if is_final_token(token, tmpdoc)
            else {"LOWER": token.lower_})
```

Can someone suggest how I can edit my code to match ALL cases for keywords (i.e., entities)?

Answer (score 2):

With the provided attributes you can only match `LOWER` or `LEMMA`, not "lowercase lemma". So if you generate this pattern:

```
{"LEMMA": "product"}
```

for a token whose lemma is `PRODUCT`, it simply won't match.

If you want to match lowercase lemmas, some options:

- postprocess the docs to lowercase lemmas before running the matcher (either separately in your script or with a custom pipeline component)
- use a custom lemmatizer that produces lowercase lemmas
- use a custom extension with a getter to return the lowercase form of the lemma for use with a `"_"` matcher pattern (a "property extension" as described here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#description)

If your only concern is matching lowercase lemmas, I'd suggest the first option as the easiest to implement and fastest to run in the matcher.

Comment: My question is not specifically about lowercase; it's about whatever is found in the text. The text can be written in title case or uppercase. We don't know what case the words are in the document, but we need to detect all cases... So, I would be very grateful if you had other ideas to match all cases.

Comment: It sounds like you should just match on `LOWER`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the simple thing to do. I need to detect plural, singular, and different conjugations.